# Refresh CSS every second?

Tags: web-development

Im developing a website. I dont have a local environment, my text editor FTPs files to the server. I want CSS changes to update on the webpage without me having to keep refreshing the page. Is there a plug in or javascript code that will refresh the CSS on a web page every second or half second?

I know there are lots of browser plugins like live reload but I have some trouble getting these to work at the best of times, and as im not working locally I dont think any of them will work for me.

Comment: Yikes. The only time I update code on a production server is if it is absolutely required. Even then, I know exactly what changes needs to be made and will update my version control with the made changes. If your computer is able, I would suggest using VirtualBox to create a development environment that somewhat matches your production environment. Do any testing there and manually refresh your page. This is just my opinion.

Comment: I normally work locally its just in this instance that I cant. Its a development server not the live site, but its not on my local computer and I have limited control over it.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this before but it looks like this JS tool might work:

http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/

***Note: Only CSS-files included before the CSSrefresh-file will be refreshed.***

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript to reload every 1 second

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function refreshTimer() {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="refreshTimer();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My page takes a while to refresh so I need to just refresh the CSS not the whole page.

Comment: if you have only a portion of the page that uses the css, make the onload call in the div tag of that section

Comment: The entire page will be being developed. Is it possible to refresh the CSS without the entire page with JS?